# C++: Reading data from a memory mapped file

Tags: c++, windows, memcpy, memory-mapped-files

I have used MapVirtualFile to map a file under Window using C++ VS2010.
The void is

```
  void*                   m_pVoiceData;
```

I would now like to fill a structure with the data.

I have been using

```
void clsMapping::FeedPitchmarksFromMap(udtPitchmarks &uAudioInfo,unsigned long int uBytePos)
{

    unsigned long int iCountPM;
    memcpy(&iCountPM, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[uBytePos],sizeof(int));

    uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks.resize(iCountPM);

    for (unsigned long int i=0;i<iCountPM;i++)
    {
        iBytePos+=sizeof(int);
        unsigned long int iByteStart;
        memcpy(&iByteStart, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],4);

        iBytePos+=sizeof(int);
        unsigned long int iByteCount;
        memcpy(&iByteCount, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],4);

        iBytePos+=sizeof(int);
        unsigned int iF0;
        memcpy(&iF0, &((char*)(m_pVoiceData))[iBytePos],4);

        uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i].ByteStart =iByteStart;
        uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i].ByteCount =iByteCount;
        uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[i].F0 =iF0;
    }
}
```

As one can see, I am currently using memcpy to get the data. 
Is there a faster way to do "get my data over"?

Comment: You declare a `long` variable and copy `sizeof(int)` to it. Remember that `sizeof(long)` doesn't have to equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Also, is it really `iByteStart` as argument? Or is it `iBytePos` you mean?

Comment: Thank you. I mistyped it and edited my post now. And yep, I made a mistake assuming the size of int and long is the same. However, in my case it is, so no error (for now). I will change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "fastest" would probably be simple assignment:

```
unsigned long iCountPM = 
    *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_pVoiceData) + uBytePos);
```

Can be used instead for all those `memcpy` calls in the function.

Comment: And that would be faster or just more elegant?

Comment: @tmighty Well, both I would guess, as it's one function call and (possible) loop less.

Comment: I'm suggesting even further, that if the memory-mapped file is laid out exactly the same as an array of the structures in memory, _all_ elements of the array can be copied with a single `memcpy`. That's where it's even faster than "simple assignment".

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your memory-mapped file has exactly the same alignment and padding as the type of your `uAudioInfo.Pitchmarks[0]` (presumably a struct of some kind), you can just use one single `memcpy` to copy the whole lot, rather than `memcpy`ing individual fields like you're currently doing.

Comment: You have seen my code. Can you tell me how I could do that in one rush?